# Opening a specific settings menu under iOS 13, Swift 5.x

Tags: swift, url, settings

iOS 12, Swift 5.x

Using this code to open setting, works ok... but opens my apps settings and I wanted it to open WiFi settings? Read a few suggestions this is simply not possible in later versions of iOS... but... I was hoping that might be a wrong answer ...

```
if let url = URL(string:UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
     if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
       UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
     }
}
```

Can I ask it to open a specific settings menu, after the one linked to the network settings ideally?

Answer (score 2):

This opens just the Settings app (tested on iOS 14.4.5). I couldn't find a way to open a specific setting. But if you want the user to open i.e. the Wi-Fi settings, this should be a better solution, that opening your apps settings.

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "App-Prefs:")!)
```